# how to make conditional ordering in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have table with fields `task_priority`, `task_completed_time`,`task_completed`. Completed colume have values `0` and `1` and it is a primary sort. I want to make secondary sort to be `priority` if `completed` is `0` and `completed_time` if `completed` is `1`. How can i get it?

Comment: Try `ORDER BY completed ASC, IF(completed, completed_time, priority) DESC`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo SQLiteException: no such function: IF (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE (task_name LIKE ? ) ORDER BY task_completed ASC, IF (task_completed, task_completed_time, task_priority) DESC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some typo fixes i made it:

```
SELECT * FROM task_table 
WHERE (task_name LIKE ? ) 
ORDER BY task_completed ASC, 
    CASE task_completed 
        WHEN 0 THEN task_priority  
        WHEN 1 THEN task_completed_time  
    END DESC
```